# newtxmath subscript spacing too large

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath

When i try to use the newtxmath package the subscript spacing is too large and looks ugly. Is there anything which can be done to rectify this. I am not talking of the "x_n" subscript spacing but the l_p subscript spacing.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Does `l_{\!p}` look better?

Comment: @HenriMenke Kindly add that as answer. Yes It does look better. :D Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the wrong shapes, in my opinion. Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\makebox[1cm][r]{$x_p$}\sbox0{$_p$}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern-\wd0 \smash{\vrule height 1.5ex depth 4ex width 0.1pt}}

\makebox[1cm][r]{$l_p$}

\end{document}
```

which typesets `$x_p$` and `$l_p$` so that the right borders are aligned and also draws a hairline at the left border of the subscript p (of its bounding box, to be precise).

[image]

If I change `_p` with `_n` throughout, I get

[image]

Let's try `$x_n$` and `$l_p$`, by changing a bit the code; I see no real need for a correction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\makebox[1cm][r]{$x_n$\sbox0{$_n$}\kern-\wd0}%
\smash{\vrule height 1.5ex depth 4ex width 0.1pt}

\makebox[1cm][r]{$l_p$\sbox0{$_p$}\kern-\wd0}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is your example

[image]

You see that, at high resolution, the gap is not as big as it appears at low resolution.

Here are possible corrections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Let $\{x_n\}\in l_p$

Let $\{x_n\}\in l_{\mkern-1mu p}$

Let $\{x_n\}\in l_{\mkern-2mu p}$

Let $\{x_n\}\in l_{\mkern-3mu p}$

Let $\{x_n\}\in l_{\mkern-4mu p}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seeing them in comparison makes me choose the default or the `-1mu` correction at most. With `\!` you get `-3mu` which is too much.

Comment: How does 1 get the -1mu correction?? Like the last 2 images of yours look really good with the subscript spacing.

Comment: @S.C. I forgot to add the code; now it's there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way if i want all my subscripts to have -1mu spacing without having to write the \mkern command again and again what command should I be using??

Comment: @S.C. You *don't* want that. `;-)`

Comment: Why do you say so??

Comment: @S.C. Some small correction may reveal good in some situations, not in every case. In this particular case the two subscripts may appear to be at different distance (which is not, as I showed before): these are optical illusions that should be cured case by case.

Comment: Emm thanks. But I am curious to try and see what happens :P

Comment: @S.C. There's no command to do it; one can only redefine the action of `_`. But then `$\mathrm{x}_{n}$` will be wrongly kerned.

Comment: Fine then. Thanks very much for your time. Take Care :)

Answer (score 3):

In math mode you can add negative spacing using `\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Let $\{x_n\} \in l_{\!p}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]