# Spacing too large with double subscript

Tags: math-mode, spacing, pdftex, txfonts

In a document that uses the `newtx` packages, double subscripts seem to have too much spacing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  $\lambda_{\alpha_p}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Double subscript with txfonts]

The spacing with the default font looks much better:

[image: Double subscript with default font]

It also happens with `newtx` if Latin letters are used:

[image: Double subscript with Latin letters]

More pairs tested:

[image: Pairs]

Is there anything I can do at the "user" level (short of inserting `\!` all over the place) to fix this?

Related, but not the same: [newtxmath subscript spacing too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244251/8057).

Comment: If you think that certain character pairings look wrong, you should inform the designer of that font or the maintainer of that package. Maybe they can fix the kerning.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I've sent a message to Michael Sharpe, the author and maintainer of newtxmath.

Comment: Ideally, the `newtxmath` package would offer an option called `subscriptcorrection`, similar to the one already offered by the `mtpro2` package. (My answer -- see below -- shows how to use the `mtpro2` package with the `subscriptcorrection` option.) See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248793/5001) by @egreg for the code that implements the subscript correction for *any* math font package. Good news: As `newtxmath` and `mtpro2` are both Times Roman math clones, you should be able to use Enrico's code "out of the box", i.e., without needing to modify any of the spacing corrections.

Answer (score 2):

No guarantee! Might effect parts of your document which you do not want to change.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand_[1]{\sb{\mspace{-1.5mu}#1}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    $\lambda_{\alpha_p}$

    $l_{\alpha_p}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or is the spacing before $p$ still too wide?

Comment: @krlmlr For `a` instead of `\alpha` it looks better. That is a problem of kerning from the font design. If you have some single pairings you do not like, just define something like `\newcommand*{\subp}{_{\mspace{-2.5mu}p}}` (not tested) or alike.

Comment: Can I fix the kerning myself, so that perhaps I can later show my findings to the font designer/package author?

Comment: @krlmlr I guess you can: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10455. But this will be some work.

Comment: Enrico [has shown](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248793/5001) how to adapt the `subscriptcorrection` option of the `mtpro2` package to *any* math font package.

Answer (score 1):

For this math font and combination of letters, I think you need to insert a negative thinspace, `\!`, i.e., write `\alpha_{\!p}` instead of just `\alpha_!p`. This applies to cases where `\alpha` is on the baseline or in the first subscript position.

The following screenshot shows the letter combinations *with* this adjustment on the left, and *without* the adjustment on the right.

Note that, depending on the font in use, there will always be some combinations of letters for which manual spacing adjustments are needed in math mode in order to achieve the optimal typographic look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\alpha_{\!p}$           $\alpha_p$

$\lambda_{\alpha_{\!p}}$ $\lambda_{\alpha_p}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you choose to work with the [MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) math font package instead of the `newtxmath` package, you can get the subscript positioning correction automatically by specifying the option `subscriptcorrection`. (Both `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` are Times Roman Math fonts.) Note that whereas the full `mtpro2` package is not free of charge, its "lite" subset -- which is all that's needed for this example -- is in fact free of charge. Observe in the screenshot below that hardly any difference is visible between the version with the explicit `\!` correction on the left and the automatic correction on the right. (Well, there's a tiny difference, as my manual correction amounts to `\mkern-3mu`, whereas the automatic one by the `mtpro2` package amounts to `\mkern-2mu`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\alpha_{\!p}$           $\alpha_p$

$\lambda_{\alpha_{\!p}}$ $\lambda_{\alpha_p}$
\end{document}
```