# Too much horizontal spacing after double subscript

Tags: spacing, subscripts

The use of the additional subscript *1* on *s* below adversely affects the spacing afterwards:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Actual:
$\begin{array}{l}
f_{s_1}(x) \\
f_{s}(x)
\end{array}$ \\

Desired:
$\begin{array}{l}
f_{s_1}\hspace{-0.13em}(x) \\
f_{s}(x)
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

I’ve tried this with other fonts and the problem doesn’t seem to be specific to `article` or the fonts in use here. Is there is a convenient way to “fix” this?

(I don’t believe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263056/spacing-too-large-with-double-subscript) is related.)

Comment: It is also worth noting that the formatting on the “1” itself is also troublesome (it’s too big), so perhaps there are multiple interacting problems here.

Comment: Your `\hspace` solution seems to work fine, but ``\!`` also provides a "negative space".